# 'detectMultiScale' requires a 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am new to opencv and am trying to detect a face in an image however I am having problems with this line of code

```py
faces = cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(1,1))
```

I get this error

```py
TypeError: descriptor 'detectMultiScale' requires a 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I have tried doing research on this error however nothing seems to tell me why this is happening and how to fix it.
full code

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\.py pics\\pic.jpg")

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Astroid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray_img,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(10, 10)
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

print(type(faces))
print(faces)

for x, y, w, h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("pic", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is the CascadeClassifier you are using?

Comment: how do i find out what CascadeClassifier i have?

Comment: Go to the site-packages and find cv2 > data > all the classifiers are there.

Comment: you have to create a cascade classifier like: face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
 and then use face_cascade.detectMultiScale function

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not so wrong, i guess you have not mentioned the CascadeClassifier in your code.
e.g.

```
# Classifier you want to use
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

...
...

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
...
```

Here's a code that executes:

```
import cv2

# don't add 1 in arg
img = cv2.imread("your path to the image")

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('your Path to 
 haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray_img,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(10, 10)
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

print(type(faces))
print(faces)

for x, y, w, h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("pic", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ok, just so i can get a bit more understanding of whats going on here, there are different types of CascadeClassifiers in cv2 so I need to specify which CascadeClassifier im using before using the detectMultiScale functions? so then what is the ('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') referring to ?

Comment: @JasonRieder Correct you need to provide what classifier you want to use. each Classifier is created with the features in an XML version. The one i'm referring to is horizontal and vertical features. Just like this there are upperbody, lowerbody etc. classifiers available.

Comment: ok thanks that makes sense, just one more question, how do i know what CascadeClassifier i need to use for different purposes?

Comment: @JasonRieder It definately depends on you. my aplogies i have not tried all of them to give you an insight which is better and which is not. Usually you can try all of them and see which one suits you.
e.g. there are multiple face classifiers available you can test all of them.

Comment: so i put that line of code into the editor , 
`
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces = cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(1,1))
`however the same error shows up, iv put the full code in the question if you want to see

Comment: You need to read image with cv2.imread()
```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\.py pics\\pic.jpg")
```
This is wrong

Comment: iv updated the code in the question is that what you meant?
same error btw...

Comment: @JasonRieder  i've added a working code for you, check it out.

Comment: very sorry this is getting ridiculous iv updated the code in the question the same error is getting  displayed...

Comment: Jason, the code i did paste that works fine on my system, but if it is stil showing the error then either it is not able to load the cascade classifier or may be not so sure but problem with opencv on your system. try tweaking around a bit. may be you will find the solution.

Comment: there are several pretrained cascade classifiers. If you need one with different properties (e.g. to detecf cars) you might have to train your own one.

Answer (score 0):

so after all that, I tweaked with the code a bit and I honestly have no idea what was wrong but here is the final working code.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\.py pics\\image.png")

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade =  
cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Astroid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray_img,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
)

print(type(faces))
print(faces)

for x, y, w, h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("image", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```